How to made image "shiftable/scrollable" if image width more than screen width
I have Fragment
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#3E3E3E">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop">

      </LinearLayout>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I place image with this function
    Bitmap imgBitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(this.getContext(),imgFile);
    binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);

where getBitmapFromAsset is
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String strName) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream istr;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return bitmap;
}

And receive strange result - device width for example 1344 pt, sometimes small image scalable with lost resolution, but wide image (for example with 2000pt width) fit to device and fit resolution.
I need opposite result - image never should be stretch (if image has small width), but if image wider than device (3000 pt width for example) - image allow to be shifting/scrolling (by one finger or two).
How is possible?
